# Calculate cube by looping with logarithm

Tags: java

I need to build a loop that does this: 3 = Math.log10( result of number squared )/Math.log10( number inputed ) number_to_be_cubed

```
double cubed;
double answer;

answer = 1;
cubed = 0;

while (cubed <= 3) {
    cubed = (double) Math.log( answer )/Math.log( number_to_be_cubed );
    answer ++;
}

double answer_for_cubed = answer;
System.out.println("answer_for_cubed  " + answer_for_cubed);
```

Based on the fact that A^3=B and 3=logB/logA are the same thing. Instead, I know I could use math.pow but I'm trying to solve x^3 with logs. I think it's not working because of the way java handles numbers. Is this possible? Am I looping the wrong way? I have been looking everywhere on the internet and i haven't found a problem like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double cubed = 0d;
    Double answer = 0d;

    while (cubed.compareTo(3d) <0) {
        answer ++;
        cubed = Math.log( answer )/Math.log( 4 );
        System.out.println(cubed + "   " + answer);
    }

    double answer_for_cubed = answer;
    System.out.println("answer_for_cubed  " + answer_for_cubed);
}
```

result is:

```
answer_for_cubed  64.0
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this method only works **iff** the `number_to_be_cubed` is an `integer`. For example try `Math.log( answer )/Math.log( 4.2 )`, the expected answer is `74.1` but this calculates `75`